# read a data frame in shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am completely new to shiny, apologize me if i ask too basic question.
Question 1:
How to read a data frame in shiny? like read.table. 
Here is my code:

```
ui.R
 fileInput('file1', 'Choose txt file:',
              accept=c('text', 'tab-separated-values'))
server.R
data1<-read.table(input$file1) # inside renderPlot
```

But this is not working. I want to take a tab delimited file as input.

Question 2:

How to keep two menu options in a same line, something like

```
fileInput('file1', 'Choose txt file:',
              accept=c('text', 'tab-separated-values')),

selectInput("M",  label= "Select M value:", 
                choices = 2:15)
```

How to display the above items in same line, not one below one? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

for a csv    `data <-read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE,sep="," ,quote='"')` 
for a tab delimited file `read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "")` I would advise you create a global.R file to do the reading of the data instead of doing so in a function

Comment: Thanks! As u suggested i used `data<-read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "/t")`, still no use. I used this inside render plot. Error is:`'file' must be a character string or connection`.

Comment: try using double quotes on the file name